# Expression-support workaround for older Apache httpd Versions (2.4.8)

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, mod-headers

I am in the unfortunate situation to use an older Apache httpd 2.4.8, and want to use expressions such as base64 encoding with mod_headers.

According to the documentation expr=value support was added to mod_headers in 2.4.10. What might be a viable solution to get the following configuration running on 2.4.8?

```
Header add Set-Cookie "expr=MYCOOKIE=%{base64:%{env:SOMEENVIRONMENT}}; path=/; Expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 04:14:00 GMT;"
```

This example is over-simplified. The real expression involves additional unescape and unbase64 functions. It would be cool if someone could give me a hint about if this is possible with 2.4.8 at all and what might be a feasible way implement this.

Thank you!

Mirko

- Configuration works perfectly on 2.4.54, but due to platform restrictions I have to use 2.4.8.